# Option[Serializable] does not conform to Try[String]

Tags: scala

The following code generates the compilation error `Option[serializable] does not conform to Try[String]`

In all the places where the method can return, I am returning either a `Try(String)` or `Failure(Exception)`. Given that why does compiler think I am returning `Option[Serializable]`?

```
def m1(arg1 : String, arg2 : String): Try[String] = {
    for {
      x1 <- getM1(arg1)
      x2 <- getM2(arg2)
    } yield {
      val id : Either[Exception, String]=  weirdFunction(x1, x2)
      id match {
        case Left(e) => Failure(Exception("")))
        case Right(id) => Success(id)
      }
   } getOrElse(Failure(Exception("")))
 }
```

Comment: What is the return type of  `getM1` and `getM2`?

Comment: whats the signature of getM1 and getM2?

Comment: @Ben Reich : both the methods return : Option[String]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an issue of parentheses:

```
def m1(arg1 : String, arg2 : String): Try[String] = {
    for {
      x1 <- getM1(arg1)
      x2 <- getM2(arg2)
    } yield {
      val id : Either[Exception, String]=  weirdFunction(x1, x2)
      id match {
        case Left(e) => Failure(Exception("")))
        case Right(id) => Success(id)
      }
   } /* getOrElse used to be here */
}.getOrElse(Failure(Exception("")))
```

The compiler thought you were trying to call `getOrElse` on the `Try` returned in the `yield` statement (how could it know otherwise?). Since there is a `getOrElse` method on `Try` as well as `Option`, this is a particularly confusing error message.  So, it thought you were trying to either return the `id` in the `Success` of the `yield` statement or the `Failure` afterwards.  Their least common super type is `Serializable`, and since it thought we were still wrapped in the `for` comprehension, it deduced the return type to be `Option[Serializable`.